# Como usar o teclado numérico com prompt() do JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```
var numero = -1;
var min = 0
var max = 50

while (numero < min){
    var numero = parseInt(prompt("Digite seu número entre "+min+" e "+max+"."));
    if (!numero){
        alert("Escreva algo!!!");
        numero = -1;
    }
    if(numero < 0 || numero >50){
        alert("ATENÇÂO!!\nEscreva um número entre 0 e 50");
        numero = -1;
    }
}
```

O código funciona normal mas eu gostaria que quando acessado por portáteis o teclado numérico aparecesse e não o teclado normal.

Existe alguma forma de fazer isso?

[tela mobile com teclado padrão ao usar a função prompt()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05809.jpg)

Comment: Infelizmente `window.prompt()` é limitado e por isso **não é possível**.

Answer (score 0):

Olá! A função window.prompt não permite esta operação, veja mais detalhes em : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp

Por outro lado, você pode construir o seu próprio modal, e exibir um input com type = number, ex:

```
<input type="number" id="tentacles" name="tentacles" min="10" max="100" />
```

Isto irá oferecer uma interface mais apropriada para campos numéricos. Sobre como criar um modal, veja em :
https://medium.com/@caualoewen1/desenvolvendo-um-modal-com-javascript-3262a0b29d27

Espero ter ajudado.